# Helm ConfigMap - Multiline variable in a multiline key

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to leverage a multiline variable injected into a multiline key in a helm chart configmap, but the formatting is all wonky.

For instance, the variable I'm trying to set looks like this:

```
  plugin: |
    Foo "example" {
      plugin_data {
          foo = "bar"
          foz = "baz"
      }
    }
```

And the existing configmap I'm trying to pass this to looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ template "chart.fullname" . }}
  labels:
{{ include "chart.labels" . | indent 4 }}
data:
  server.conf: |
    server {
      bind_address = "{{ .Values.config.bindAddress }}"
      bind_port = "{{ .Values.config.bindPort }}"
      log_level = "{{ .Values.config.logLevel }}"
    plugins {
      DataStore "sql" {
        plugin_data {
          database_type = "sqlite3"
        }
      }
    {{- if .Values.config.plugin -}}
    {{- toYaml .Values.config.plugin | nindent 4 -}}
    {{- end -}}
    }
```

The templated configmap comes out looking like this, which is obviously not valid YAML. Note the `|` before the templated plugin var:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example
  labels:
data:
  server.conf: |
    server {
      bind_address = "0.0.0.0"
      bind_port = "8081"
      log_level = "DEBUG"
    plugins {
      DataStore "sql" {
        plugin_data {
          database_type = "sqlite3"
        }
      }
    |
      Foo "example" {
        plugin_data {
            foo = "bar"
            foz = "baz"
        }
      }
```

But what I'm looking for is this, without the additional `|`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: example
  labels:
data:
  server.conf: |
    server {
      bind_address = "0.0.0.0"
      bind_port = "8081"
      log_level = "DEBUG"
    plugins {
      DataStore "sql" {
        plugin_data {
          database_type = "sqlite3"
        }
      }
      Foo "example" {
        plugin_data {
            foo = "bar"
            foz = "baz"
      }
```

Is this possible? These are not my helm charts, I am merely trying to add functionality to an open-source repo, so changing up the server.config isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToYaml` is redundant

values.yaml

```yaml
config:
  bindAddress: 127.0.0.1
  bindPort: 8080
  logLevel: info
  plugin: |
    Foo "example" {
      plugin_data {
          foo = "bar"
          foz = "baz"
      }
    }
```

cm.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  server.conf: |
    server {
      bind_address = "{{ .Values.config.bindAddress }}"
      bind_port = "{{ .Values.config.bindPort }}"
      log_level = "{{ .Values.config.logLevel }}"
    plugins {
      DataStore "sql" {
        plugin_data {
          database_type = "sqlite3"
        }
      }
    {{- if .Values.config.plugin }}
    {{- .Values.config.plugin | nindent 6 }}
    {{- end }}
    }
```

output

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  server.conf: |
    server {
      bind_address = "127.0.0.1"
      bind_port = "8080"
      log_level = "info"
    plugins {
      DataStore "sql" {
        plugin_data {
          database_type = "sqlite3"
        }
      }
      Foo "example" {
        plugin_data {
            foo = "bar"
            foz = "baz"
        }
      }
      
    }
```